# How does a static variable differentiate between initialization and assignments

Tags: c, initialization, static-variables, function-definition, storage-duration

I know static variables maintain their values for the entire runtime of the program even between function calls. Given the code below, what would be the value of x printed considering that x is declared as static and was initialized to zero. How does the using_static function not assign zero to the variable x during each call to the function?

```
int using_static()
{
   static int x;
   x = 0;
   x++;
   return (x);
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   i = 0;
   while (i < 5)
     {
       using_static();
       i++;
     }
   printf("%i", using_static());
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling that with warnings turned on? You're telling `printf()` to print a function pointer like it was an `int`; that's not going to work very well.

Comment: (If your code ever got that far; it has an infinite loop first).

Comment: @Shawn -- so what you are saying, if you are a variable named `i` the story never changes? `:)`

Comment: @Shawn, this isn't my actual code. I typed that here to provide some sort of insight to the question. I have edited the code now to correct the errors pointed.

Comment: And now you can run that piece of code and observe the output. And answer your own question.

Comment: @Mat code has been edited to correct the error pointed. Can you provide insight to the question, please?

Comment: A variable is initialized once and will not be initialized again with each function call.
I suspect what we see in the code __static int x;__ is not actually put in the function when the code is compiled, but is managed in different place. Each time you use variable in the function, it refer to that place.

Comment: @VladfromMoacow your edit makes the code valid, and the question meaningless. Please consider reverting.

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop? That is a perfect example where it should be a `for` loop. Also, the `return` statements don't need braces. Don't add unnecessary braces, they impair understanding the language. Don't teach yourself bad coding habits.

Comment: I suspect any compiler with optimisation enabled will optimise the whole of function to `using_static()`  to the literal `1`, at which point it optimises the loop out as **dead code** ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code sets the static variable `x` that has a default value of 0 to 0 every time the function is called an increments it so it's value won't go above 1. static variables are always initialized with a value (Implicitly with 0 in your case). The correct code would be

```
int using_static() {
    static int x = 0; // The value of x won't be reassigned to 0 on every call since it has static storage.
    // Setting x = 0 here, after it's declaration would reassign it on every call and never allow it to go above 1.
    x++; // Value becomes 1 on first call, 2 on second call and so on
    return x;
}
```

The statement where the variable was declared as `static` is the only one which doesn't reassign the variable each time the function containing it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the using_static function not assign zero to the variable x
> during each call to the function?

You are mistaken. Each time when the function is called the variable x is explicitly assigned with the value 0 due to the assignment statement

```
int using_static()
{
   static int x;
   x = 0;
   ^^^^^^
   x++;
   return (x);
}
```

So the returned value of the function is always equal to 1.

It seems you mean initialization of the variable instead of its assignment.

If you will remove the statement

```
int using_static()
{
   static int x;
   x++;
   return (x);
}
```

then the function will output sequentially

```
1 2 3 4 and so on
```

Initially the variable `x` is zero initialized. The initialization occurs before the program startup and occurs only once.

From the C Standard (5.1.2 Execution environments)

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
> their initial values) before program startup.

and (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
> or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;
>
> ....

You can imagine the function like

```
int using_static()
{
   goto L1;
   static int x = 0;

   L1: x = 0;
   x++;
   return (x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Static variables are auto initialized to zero. If need be, they can only be initialized during declaration.

so while the above code would give an output of 1, changing using_static() to

```
int using_static()
{
   static int x = 0;
   x++;
   return (x);
}
```

would give an output of 6.

Thanks to all who answered.